# Problem with my tabular

Tags: tables

I am having troubles with this table. As you can see, the table is not closed and I would like for the title of my other two columns to be centered both vertically and horizontally with the first. Any idea how can I solve it?

[image: Table1]

Here is a snippet of my script:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
\hline
\textbf{Range of the}~\\ \textbf{diameter (in mm)} & $\mathbf{N_{\mathrm{turns}}}$& $\mathbf{N_{\mathrm{turns}}}$ \textbf{per meter}\\ \hline
$0.100  \leq d < 0.250   $ & 33 & 246 \\
$0.250  \leq d < 0.355   $ & 23 & 184 \\
$0.355  \leq d < 0.500   $ & 16 & 128 \\
$0.500  \leq  d < 0.710  $ & 12 & 96 \\
$0.710  \leq d < 1.060   $ & 8  & 64 \\ \hline
\end {tabular}
\newline
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
  \hline
  \textbf{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    Range of the\\
    diameter (in mm)
  \end{tabular}}
  & $\mathbf{N_{\mathrm{turns}}}$& $\mathbf{N_{\mathrm{turns}}}$ \textbf{per meter}\\ \hline
$0.100  \leq d < 0.250   $ & 33 & 246 \\
$0.250  \leq d < 0.355   $ & 23 & 184 \\
$0.355  \leq d < 0.500   $ & 16 & 128 \\
$0.500  \leq  d < 0.710  $ & 12 & 96 \\
$0.710  \leq d < 1.060   $ & 8  & 64 \\ \hline
\end {tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you gernot ! You saved my day !